# AngularJS: ng-repeat track by obj.id doesn't reinitialise transcluded content when obj.id changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```js
function ComponentController() {
  var vm = this;
  this.$onInit = function() {
    vm.link = 'http://example.com/obj/' + vm.obj.id;
  }
}
function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.arrObjs = [{id: 1, name: "object1"},{id: 2, name: "object2"}];
    console.log('object1\'s id is ', $scope.arrObjs[0].id);
  $timeout(function() { // simulates a call to server that updates the id
    $scope.arrObjs[0].id = '3';
    console.log('object1\'s new id is ', $scope.arrObjs[0].id, '. Expected the link above to be updated with the new ID');
  }, 1000);
}
var someComponent = {
  bindings: {
    obj: '='
  },
  template: '<div>URL: <span>{{$ctrl.link}}</span></div>',
  controller: ComponentController
};

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .controller('ComponentController', ComponentController)
    .component('someComponent', someComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in arrObjs track by obj.id">
      <some-component obj="obj"></some-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the `ng-repeat` and its `someComponent` are rendered one of the objects' `obj.id` changes (using a `$timeout` in the above example). The `vm.link` for that object still carries the old id!

Now, I know that the `$onInit()` is only run once inside `someComponent`, but why doesn't `track by` re-initialise the component because the `obj.id` changed?

If Angular truly tracked an array by the `obj.id`s, it should treat an `obj` whose id changes as a completely different object and re-initialise it, no?

Obviously a `$watch` on `vm.obj.id` within `someComponent` will fix it, but is there a way without adding yet another `$watch`?

NOTE: previously I was using

```
<div ng-repeat="objID in vm.arrObjIDs track by objID" ng-init="obj = vm.fnLookUpObjByID(objID)">
  <someComponent obj="obj"></someComponent>
</div>
```

And that works perfectly!  This is exactly how I expected the `track by obj.id` to work.  But I'm trying to move away from the `ng-init` pattern.

Comment: I don't see the bindings in your component definition.

Comment: @gyc done as requested

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something somewhere in your code that you're not showing us.

The following snippet works.

init() is not a standard function though. You probably mean `$onInit()`

```js
function ComponentController() {
  var vm = this;
  console.log("not in init: " + this.obj.id);
  this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log("in init: " + vm.obj.id);
  }
}
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.arrObjs = [{id: 1, name: "object1"},{id: 2, name: "object2"}];
}
var someComponent = {
  bindings: {
    obj: '='
  },
  template: '<div>ID: <span>{{$ctrl.obj.id}}</span></div>',
  controller: ComponentController
};

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .controller('ComponentController', ComponentController)
    .component('someComponent', someComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in arrObjs track by obj.id">
      <some-component obj="obj"></some-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

If you add an asynchronous function in the middle, the compiling of the code will always be faster than the return of the async function.

Using $watch is the standard way of updating the view when data changes.
There's not other way.

Note: With components you can use $onChanges() but in this particular case it won't trigger since you have to [change the reference of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349915/triggering-onchanges-for-updated-one-way-binding#answer-36442648) for it to update. $onChanges() calls $watch in any case.

Comment: Many thanks for the code snippit. I've updated my question with a modified version which is more to the question I was asking. I didn't know about the new `$onInit` but I don't believe that is any different in my case to executing my own `init()`

Comment: Yes, you're right, but my main question is about track by, not component initialisation.  "Now, I know that the `$onInit()` is only run once inside `someComponent`, but why doesn't `track by` re-initialise the component because the `obj.id` changed?".

Comment: @poshest ok, I see. In this case you should put the ng-repeat inside the component template and pass the array to some-component. This will solve your $watch problem